Traefik with service in separate docker-compose file stops working when using multiple networks
As a relative docker and Traefik novice, I am trying to get Traefik with multiple services in separate docker-compose files running. For illustration purposes, the first service A is a simple web service (nginxdemos/hello) with an additional database (postgres).
My traefik/docker-compose.yml is as follows:
version: '3.8'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080" # Traefik Dashboard
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true

The service-A/docker-compose.yml looks as follows:
version: '3.8'

services:
  service-a:
    image: nginxdemos/hello
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@service-a-db:5432/dbname
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.service-a.rule=Host(`a.dock.er`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.service-a.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    networks:
#      - service-a-network
      - web
    ports:
      - 9080:80 # just for testing
#    depends_on:
#      - service-a-db


  service-a-db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - service-a-network

networks:
  service-a-network:
    internal: true
  web:
    external: true

With this configuration, the service is accessible through Traefik via 'A.dock.er'.
However, as soon as I add the additional 'service-a-network' network (as well as the 'depends_on' option) to service-a, the service is no longer accessible via Traefik (but still accessible via port 9080).
I am lost, what is causing this. I believe this should be the correct configuration, with separating internal sub-services into their own network and thus having the main service in both the 'public' Traefik network as well as the internal network.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Unrelated to your question, your use of depends_on is effectively a no-op. To be effective, you need to use the extended form of that option along with health checks in the database container.

Can you combine all of this into a single Compose file, and delete all of the manual networks: setup?  If everything is in a single file, Compose's out-of-the-box networking setup should work fine for Compose-scale applications.

When you have a service connected to multiple networks, traefik will see multiple ip addresses for that service...and it will pick a random one when it tries to connect. This won't work if it picks an address on a network to which it is not connected.
You can tell traefik which network to use by setting the traefik.docker.network label on the service with multiple connections. If we rewrite service-a like this, it will work as expected:
services:
  service-a:
    image: nginxdemos/hello
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@service-a-db:5432/dbname
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.service-a.rule=Host(`a.dock.er`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.service-a.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
    networks:
      - service-a-network
      - web

With that in place:
$ curl -s http://localhost -H Host:a.dock.er
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
.
.
.

